# How do I create a new column based on another column that has keyname and keyvalue pairs

Tags: python, dataframe

I loaded a csv file into a DF using read_csv. The resulting DF has below columns:

Name, Dept, JobType, Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4, Address5

The data in Address columns (Address1, Address2, Address3, Address4 and Address5) is structured like below

```
{'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}
{'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Broadway'}
{'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'New York'}
{'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'NY'}
{'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}
```

The address pieces do not appear in any specific order in the 5 columns. For example, Address1 may contain Zip in one record, street # in another and state in another. Below is a sample DF:

```
data = [['Tom', 10, 'Business Analyst',{'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'},{'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Broadway'},{'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'New York'},{'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'NY'},{'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}], ['David', 10, 'Data Analyst',{'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '23456'},{'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'Atlanta'},{'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '11111'},{'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Main St'},{'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'GA'}], ['Nick', 10, 'Data Engineer',{'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'NY'},{'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'},{'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '34567'},{'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Broadway'},{'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'New York'}]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Dept', 'JobType', 'Address1', 'Address2', 'Address3', 'Address4', 'Address5'])
    print(df.to_string())
    Name  Dept           JobType                                                      Address1                                                           Address2                                                      Address3                                                           Address4                                                     Address5
0    Tom    10  Business Analyst  {'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}  {'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Broadway'}   {'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'New York'}             {'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'NY'}      {'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}
1  David    10      Data Analyst       {'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '23456'}         {'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'Atlanta'}  {'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '11111'}   {'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Main St'}       {'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'GA'}
2   Nick    10     Data Engineer        {'AddressItemName': 'State', 'AddressItemValue': 'NY'}            {'AddressItemName': 'Zip', 'AddressItemValue': '12345'}  {'AddressItemName': 'StreetNo', 'AddressItemValue': '34567'}  {'AddressItemName': 'StreetName', 'AddressItemValue': 'Broadway'}  {'AddressItemName': 'City', 'AddressItemValue': 'New York'}
```

I want to create separate columns for Street#, StreetName, City, State and Zip with appropriate values from the address columns. I want the above DF to be like below DF:

```
data = [['Tom', 10, 'Business Analyst','12345','Broadway','New York','NY','12345'], ['David', 10, 'Data Analyst', '11111','Main St','Atlanta','GA','23456'], ['Nick', 10, 'Data Engineer','34567','Broadway','New York','NY','12345']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Dept', 'JobType', 'StreetNo', 'StreetName', 'City', 'State', 'Zip'])
df1

    Name  Dept           JobType StreetNo StreetName      City State    Zip
0    Tom    10  Business Analyst    12345   Broadway  New York    NY  12345
1  David    10      Data Analyst    11111    Main St   Atlanta    GA  23456
2   Nick    10     Data Engineer    34567   Broadway  New York    NY  12345
```

I was planning to iterate through the DF for each address piece. That will be 5 iterations through the entire DF for 5 address info. I was wondering if there is a better way to do that.

Comment: Show use expected output

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can create preprocessing layer before doing converting into df like below code and then convert

```
def get_strctured_data(list_row):
    temp_dict = {}
    temp_dict['Name']=list_row[0]
    temp_dict['Dept']=list_row[1]
    temp_dict['JobType']=list_row[2]
    for temp in list_row[3:]:
        if type(temp)==dict:
            temp_dict[temp['AddressItemName']]=temp['AddressItemValue']
    return temp_dict
data = [get_strctured_data(list_row) for list_row in data]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for!